# Can Lennard-Jones parameters (epsilon) be zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, atomic-physics, potential-energy, physical-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

I was told that very often, intermolecular potential parameters (e.g. Lennard-Jones or Moorse etc.) are determined empirically via manual adjustment to reproduce experimental properties such as densities, vapor pressure, etc.

For a molecule containing 3 atom types, I recently came across a paper whose author literally set 2 atom type's epsilons to zero and tune the only remaining atom type's $\varepsilon$ and $\sigma$.

$$\varepsilon_1 = 0$$
$$\varepsilon_2 = 0$$
$$\varepsilon_3 \neq 0$$

They claim that the 2 atom types are believed to be isolated and play little role in non-bonded interactions.

My instinct is that such implementation is physically incorrect, but I would like to know the physics community's view on this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1021/ct9006053